# Why gunicorn is not serving static files?

Tags: nginx, docker, django, gunicorn, docker-compose

I am having trouble with my django, docker, nginx, and gunicorn setup. I cannot get the static files to show when running the server even after I `collectstatic` them. And when I have nginx, I either get an error saying the port I am using is already allocated, or, if I change the port, I get "bad gateway" but am still able to use the port gunicorn is using -in my case, port 8000.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: rapid_goat_postgres_server_1
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: rapid_goat_nginx_1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: rapid_goat_django
    command: bash -c "chmod -R 755 . && cd rapidgoat_scraper_product && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && gunicorn rapidgoat_scraper.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 6"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My nginx config file:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /code/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

With the above two files as they are, I get the following error when running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
ERROR: for 693800faea42_693800faea42_693800faea42_my_nginx_docker_container Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my_nginx_docker_container (48eab4028fad0c54d8bbf5669fe746c24f293cfeb11dc57c8566d4010a995a83): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my_nginx_docker_container (48eab4028fad0c54d8bbf5669fe746c24f293cfeb11dc57c8566d4010a995a83): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

And then when I remove the nginx service from the docker-compose.yml file, I can get the gunicorn server up, but it does not serve the static files. I am also using in app templates so my django project structure loosk like this:

```
- project
-- __init__.py
-- settings.py
-- urls.py
-- wsgi.py

- appname
-- migrations
-- static
--- appname
... then rest of static files like js, css, images... etc
-- templates
--- appname
... then all of my html files. I am using django templating.
-- admin.py
-- apps.py
-- forms.py
-- models.py
-- tests.py
-- views.py
```

I am also using django 2.0.3

**Edit**:

Here is the same files when I remove nginx -same as when I change the port for nginx- and gunicorn does not serve the static:

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: rapid_goat_postgres_server_1
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: rapid_goat_django
    command: bash -c "chmod -R 755 . && cd rapidgoat_scraper_product && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && gunicorn rapidgoat_scraper.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 6"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Oh, and my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
RUN mkdir /static
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Comment: Don't try to run two services on the same port. That won't work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What about serving static files? It still does not work even when I do run the services on separate ports, as I mentioned.

Comment: Well, fix one problem, so you can eliminate it, and then you can fix the other problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had mentioned in my post that I did try another port for nginx. In fact, it is no different than just removing it from services -as I had mentioned i had done. Either way, Gunicorn that is exposed at port 8000 is not serving the static content even when I do the `collectstatic` command for django.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have edited my question